# Query to find least total price for an area between two items

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's a (simplified) table with sample elements:

```
Item      Area      Price
Gas       Miami     6.00
Gas       LA        8.00
Gas       Dallas    2.00
Corn      Miami     2.00
Corn      LA        2.00
Corn      Dallas    5.00
Oil       Miami     8.00
Oil       LA        9.00
Oil       Dallas    3.00
```

I want the area with both the lowest cost of corn and gas. So in this table the answer would be Dallas since the sum of the price of corn and gas there is 7.00 (In Miami it's 8.00 and in LA it's 10.00). I'd appreciate any sort of ideas on how to get this done.

(Note: I only give the price of oil so you know there are countless more items on the list, as there are more areas for each item.)

Answer (score 2):

This is an aggregation query with an `order by`:

```
select area, sum(price) as sumprice
from simplifiedtable t
where item in ('gas', 'corn')
group by area
having sum(item = 'gas') = 1 and sum(item = 'corn') = 1
order by sum(price) asc
limit 1;
```

Note that the `having` clause ensures that the areas have both products.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Gordon. This is actually pretty similar to something I cooked up a few minutes ago, but it definitely helps to know we're on the same page. ;) It's assumed each area has a price listing for every item (I should have mentioned that) so the Having clause was omitted from my solution. Also, ASC orders by smallest first, so I used that instead of DESC.

Comment: @Jose . . . You do indeed ask for the lowest price.